# Determining a basis for a space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine a basis from the following set of second degree polynomials. Does this basis
>   span the space of the second degree polynomials? What is the dimension of the (sub)space that it
>   spans?
>   $$p_1 ( x ) = 4 x + 1$$ $$p_2 ( x ) = x^2 − 2 x + 3$$ $$p_3 ( x ) = 3 x − 2$$ $$p_4 ( x ) = x^2 − x + 5$$
>   (Hint: Use the standard basis for the space of second degree polynomials. Work with coordinate
>   vectors written relative to this basis)

I couldn't get the hint. I don't know what to do. Somebody?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Using the standard basis $(1,X,X^2)$ for $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$, you have $p_1 = (1,4,0)$, $p_2 = (3,-2,1)$, $p_3=(-2,3,0)$ and $p_4=(5,-1,1)$. The question now becomes: what is the span of these 4 vectors? And given this representation, can you extract a basis (viewing the polynomials as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$?)

(Note that the dimension is at most 3, in any case)

Comment: Viewing the polynomials as vectors, I found the span as R$^{3}$. Now I  can say those vectors span the space of the second degree polynomials, right? Thank you.

Comment: If the vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, then yes, the polynomials span $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$.

Comment: I could see they span $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I have difficulty in explaining it. Could you help me?

Comment: Show that the first three vectors are linearly independent: i.e., that if $a\cdot p_1+b\cdot p_2 + c\cdot p_3 = (0,0,0) $ (the $p_i$'s seen as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$), then $a=b=c=0$. Showing $b=0$ is immediate as you must have (for the third coordinate) $a\cdot 0 + b\cdot 1+c\cdot 0 = 0$; the other ones (that is, $a,c$) then are not difficult.